# Checkboxes on Job Search use an "AND" criteria instead of "OR" criteria

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

When looking at the jobs available on Stack Overflow, the job search offers a few choices:

[image]

Due to the nature of the choice "Offers Relocation" or "Allows Remote", I would expect the resulting search would be the product of all the searches that allow **either** Relocation or Remote work; instead (Based on the results), it appears to be an "AND" search.

#### Jobs that Just offer Relocation:

[image]

#### Jobs that just offer Remote Work:

[image]

#### Jobs that allow both remote work and relocation:

[image]

Expected behavior: For criteria like "Remote work" and "Relocation", it should be an "Or" search between them, or a little more clear that it is not.

Comment: *"I would expect the resulting search would be the product of all the searches that allow either Relocation or Remote work"* Really? The way it behaves now is the way I expected. I think of it as a filter, so that only those results that match all filters are included.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara If I'm checking boxes in the specific case of "relocation" and "remote work", I'd expect to get results for either; since those are somewhat mutually exclusive goals: I either want relocation, or I want remote work, and even in the worst case; I want either.  I never want a job that offers both, since at most I'll only take them up on one.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that makes sense. Not sure how "Visa Sponsorship" would factor in to this. I could see people wanting only "Relocation" + "Visa Sponsorship". I guess I always do the "Allows Remote" search separate.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Filters in the UI are currently AND queries. You can get the result you desire by using [advanced search](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/help). E.g. `relocation:true or remote:true`. I'll discuss tomorrow whether we should be changing UI filters as you suggest. Not sure how visa sponsorship should factor in here...

Answer (score 1):

The reason these are checkboxes (and not radio buttons) is because they aren't exclusive items. As **Dean** mentioned in the comments above:

> Filters in the UI are currently AND queries. You can get the result you desire by using [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/help). E.g. `relocation:true` or `remote:true.`

People may want to review jobs which offer both or one of the two options. They might have a preference, but by selecting both it returns all jobs which offer either. This can help people make a more informed decision ("I can say I'm okay with remote because no one offering relocation looked interesting to me or was in a location I would consider moving to.").

Comment: That's the problem. Checking both doesn't return all jobs that offers either; it returns all jobs that offer *both*.